# how to assign char to char* in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, assign

I'm trying to assign the content inside the name1 and sname1 to newnode->name and newnode->sname. But it shows up "error: invalid array assignment". I'm just a beginner, can anyone show me the way?

```
class records
{   
   struct student
   {
      char name[30];
      char sname[30];
   };
   ...
};
...

void record :: loadRecord
{ 
   student *newnode;
   char name1[30], sname1[30];
   newnode = new student;
   ifstream in_stream("file.txt");
   ...
   while(in_stream >> name1 >> sname1)
   {
   ...
   newnode->name = name1;  //error
   newnode->sname = sname1; //error, help!
   ...
   } 
}
```

Comment: you can't simply use `operator =` with arrays and expect them to be copied. Use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: Use `strcpy(newnode->name, name1)`

Comment: It's C++! Use std::string!